# Delete records older than 3 months in AS/400

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

I have a table called transactions which contains *Customer Name* (custname), *Transaction Date* (trxdate). I need to delete values older than 3 months.

**trxdate** is CHAR (6) in format `YYMMDD` like `220611`.

I am using this in an `SQLRPGLE` but it is not working meaning that the table does not get modified after running it, I tried that too from **DBeaver** for the same result.

`Delete from Trans WHERE trxdate < CURRENT DATE- 3 MONTHS;`

I am thinking that CURRENT DATE is wrong, so how to convert that to `YYMMDD`?

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use?

Comment: On AS/400 it is ALWAYS DB2 for i.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using DB2 you can try:

```
select TO_DATE('220611', 'YYMMDD') trx from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

First, you need to convert char data to date type to compare.

```
Delete from Trans WHERE TO_DATE(trxdate, 'YYMMDD')< CURRENT DATE- 3 MONTHS;
```

For other database systems, the logic is same.

Comment: Please check out: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=e7a5e35a6104d5f19cd51cb5758f9612